# Do UNIX Domain Sockets Overflow?

Tags: unix-sockets

When you create a UNIX socket using socat and send data to it, but do not have another socat instance connecting to that socket, what will happen then?

What happens if you write massive amounts of data to a UNIX socket and never read it? Is there a buffer that overflows? Is it ring-buffered?

Comment: It should probably block the writer, just like with pipes.

Comment: So in my example socat will block at some point? Can those sockets be driven non-blocking?

Comment: AFAIK, on linux, you can set pretty much any filedescriptor that's normally blocking into nonblocking mode, either on creation (`socket`, `open`) or later with `fnctl`. In nonblocking mode, you get `EAGAIN` on operations that would otherwise block.

Comment: Is this possible using command line tools or do I have to fire up my C compiler? When it's non-blocking, does it just drop the incoming data?

Comment: If a tool is designed to work with a socket in non-blocking mode then it would set a socket appropriately and treat all exchanges in accordance with its design. You can't control externally how the tool would perform IO on a socket unless that tool provides you a way to control its behavior by means of its config file(s) or command line options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unix sockets are reliable. If the reader doesn't read, the writer blocks. If the socket is a datagram socket, each write is paired with a read. If the socket is a stream socket, the kernel may buffer some bytes between the writer and the reader, but when the buffer is full, the writer will block. Data is never discarded, except for buffered data if the reader closes the connection before reading the buffer.

Comment: I wouldn't call that reliable, it's just what it is. By the way, the limit I got on Linux 4.4 x64 was 180 KiB.

Comment: @MaxRied Unix sockets are reliable, as opposed so lossy. It means that they don't lose messages.

Comment: Yes, all types of Unix domain sockets (datagram, stream and sequenced-packet) are reliable, in-order delivery mechanisms.  That is, they don't drop data unless the receiver terminates or closes the connection without receiving the data first. Typically, they operate in blocking mode by default, but can be placed in non-blocking mode.